# Alterar o status de um registro no banco de dados por ID via método post

Tags: php, symfony

Preciso alterar o status de um objeto cadastrado no banco de dados, a partir do ID deste objeto, uma vez que eu clique no botão correspondente. Como faço para passar para minha função no **controller** o ID referente aquele objeto?

O que eu devo inserir no meu button HTML?

Botão HTML:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-danger" name="acao" value="desligar" id="{{ cooperado.getId() }}">Desligar</button>
```

Função no controller:

```
public function acaoBotoes()
{
    switch ($_POST['acao']) {
        case 'desligar':
            $id = $_POST['???'];
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $cooperado = $em->getRepository(Cooperado::class)->find($id);

            $cooperado->setStatus('DE')
                ->setDataDesligamento(\DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', date('Y-m-d')));
            $em->flush();

            return $this->redirectToRoute('cooperados');

            break;
```

Na variável $id eu preciso pegar o ID vindo do button da view, então tratar na função a mudança de status deste objeto. Este 'case' irá tratar a mudança de status. Preciso clicar em "desligar" e alterar o status de um cooperado de Ativo para Desligado, conforme abaixo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode adicionar um:

`<input type="hidden" value="id" name="id">`

E recuperalo assim:

`$_POST['id']`

Comment: Excelente, Marcelo. Isso funcionou perfeitamente. Obrigado!